# XCode MapKit, Points

Tags: xcode, location, mapkit

I would like to be able to touch a point on the map, and it returns me a lat long, that simple. Does the library cater for that?

Answer (score 0):

This should to the trick:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = [mapView convertPoint:aCgPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView]; // or any other view
```

See also [MKMapView Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)